# What is a possible software for simulating binary star systems?

Tags: binary-star, n-body-simulations, software

I would like to define both initial velocities and masses of components so that orbits may be either elliptical of hyperbolic. Is there any software to make such simulation?

Unfortunately, Binary Star Combined Solution Package is out of date and NASA online plotter supports only circular orbits.

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps NEMO? http://bima.astro.umd.edu/nemo/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mathematica. For details take a look at my simulation [here](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/preview.html?draft/21067/000006/FourBody3DSimulation) for gravity and http://yukterez.ist.org/4kp2 for gravity plus electric charge.

Answer (score 3):

[MESA](http://mesa.sourceforge.net/)

It is designed specifically for stellar evolution. There are many modules that you can play around with, including binary interaction.

Answer (score 2):

mikeonly,

I stumbled across PHOEBE code the other day in another response in this forum.  I started looking into it.

"PHOEBE stands for PHysics Of Eclipsing BinariEs. It is a tool for modeling eclipsing binary stars based on photometric, spectroscopic, interferometric and/or polarimetric data." -- abstracted from About Phoebe webpage.

Perhaps this can fulfill your needs.  I've not yet installed and looked at it.
It is developed by a group of professional astronomers from around the world.

Tom Kosvic

Answer (score 1):

I use Wolfram Mathematica to produce model of systems, bodies and parameters. There are probably a plethora of math programs which may also.

A good resource are 'programmable notebooks' produced from Mathematica, demonstrations of these notebooks can be found at the [Wolfram Demonstrations Project](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/index.html). The system Wolfram has integrated is a very advanced programmable environment, however from first glance there was nothing available in the demonstrations project, at least nothing simple.